# Pandas: Matching string using fuzzywuzzy and retrieve the value of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe `df` as follows.

```
33KV Feeder      11KV Feeder     Circle_name          Codes
Shree Gopal                         SPS            33ShreeGopal_DPS
                  Jai Balaji        LRS            Jai_Balajilaji_LRS
Mithapur-1                          SPS            33Mithapur-1_SPS
                  Coal Board No. 2  LRS            Coal_Board_2_LRS
Mithapur-2                          DPS            33Mithapur-2_DPS
```

**Objective:** I want to match a user input (Feeder Name and Circle_name) in both `33KV Feeder` and `11KV Feeder` and then retrieve the value in `Codes`. For example, if an user gives an input as `Mithapur` and `SPS` then the logic should retrieve `33KV Mithapur-1_SPS`. If the user gives `Coal Board` as feeder name and `LRS` then it should pick `Coal Board o. 2_LRS`

What I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz,process
df = pd.read_csv(file_path,encoding="ISO-8859-1")
feeder_input = input() # Lets say Mithapur
circle_input = input() # Lets say SPS
match_feeder = process.extract(feeder_input,data['11KV Feeder'],scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
match_circle = process.extract(feeder_input,data['Circle name'],scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
if match_feeder[0][1] > 60 match_circle[0][1] > 90:
      z = df.loc[data[['11Kv Feeder','33Kv Feeder']].str.contains(match_feeder[0][0]).any(1) & df['Circle_name'].str.contains(match_circle[0][0]),['Codes']].iloc[0]
      print(z)
```

The above code throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I changed the `z` as follows

```
z=data.loc[data[['11Kv Feeder','33Kv Feeder']].eq(match_feeder[0][0]).any(1) & data['Circle_name'].str.contains(match_circle[0][0]),['Codes']]
```

The result is throwing an Empty DataFrame. Rather, I should have got `33KV Mithapur-1_SPS` as the value for `z`.

If I remove the `match_circle` from above then I get the following outputs.

```
Mithapur-1_SPS
Mithapur-2_DPS
```

Now my question is how can I effectively include two inputs and retrieve the correct `Codes`? Where I am missing out on the above codes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found a solution for this. I have just tweaked the `match_feeder` as follows

```
match_feeder = process.extractOne(feeder_input,data['Name of the 11Kv Feeder'],scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
```

Also I have changed the following when `if` statement is started:

```
if (match_feeder[1] > 60) and (match_circle[0][1] > 90):
    z = df.loc[data[['11Kv Feeder','33Kv Feeder']].eq(match_feeder[0]).any(1) & data['Circle Name'].str.contains(match_circle[0][0]),['Codes']].iloc[0]
    print(z)
```

I hope this problem and its solution as presented above might be useful for someone else.